# Nullpointer Exception while performing mathematical caliculations on user entered data in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception

I have a html form and I need to get the form data in servlet, then i need to do some mathematical operations with that data. But when I am getting null pointer exception while performing the mathematical operation. I am not able to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.. following is my piece of code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class InterestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String amount=request.getParameter("wpamt");
        String time=request.getParameter("prd");
        int amt = Integer.parseInt(amount.trim());
        int period = Integer.parseInt(time.trim());

        int interest=(amt * period)/100;
        out.println("for"+period+"years the interest would be"+interest);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to check request.getParameter is correctly written then before parsing check for null

Comment: @amritpal singh:how to check that?

Comment: @ajj: how to add the error log?

Comment: Copy the error which you are getting at your work place. Edit the question and add it with the side title saying 'Error log': It is not that hard !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String amount=request.getParameter("wpamt");
String time=request.getParameter("prd");
int amt = Integer.parseInt(amount.trim());
int period = Integer.parseInt(time.trim());
```

If this is where you are getting a NullPointerException (hard to tell without a stack trace and line numbers), one of the parameters is missing (not posted by the client).

If it makes sense to proceed with default values, you can do

```
int amt = amount != null ? Integer.parseInt(amount.trim()): 100;
int period = period != null ? Integer.parseInt(time.trim()) : 5;
```

Note that you will also get exceptions if the parameter contains something that is not a number.

Comment: hi tell me how to add stack trace to this program?

Comment: i dont need default values i getting values from html form

Comment: Maybe you are not getting the values. Check the parameter names, add some debugging output.

Comment: tell me how to do debugging operations?

Answer (score 0):

Either your `amount` or `time` variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the parameters `wpamt` or `prd` is missing in your response, then on of the `getParameter` method returns a null reference and then the NPE is thrown, when the virtual machine tries to call `trim()` on that *null pointer*.

To verify, add some simple debugging code at the beginning of your method:

```
System.out.println("Parameter names - Start");
for (Object param:request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
  System.out.println(param);
}
System.out.println("Parameter names - End");
```

This dumps a list of all parameters to your console

Answer (score 0):

```
String amount=request.getParameter("wpamt");
    String time=request.getParameter("prd");
```

it might be

*your UI controls names **wpamt and prd** are not mateched with jsp controls names.*.

check textbox names are same what you have used in getParameter.